# What does this mean? Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool

Tags: haskell

I was studying when I found a function `elem` of this type:

```
Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

What does the `Eq a =>` mean?

Comment: Building intuition: if a is a thing that can be compared, and you give a list of as to compare against, and the function name is elem (element), you can generally guess what the fn does from the type signature and name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Eq a` is a so called class constraint. It means that the type substituted for `a` needs to implement the `Eq` typeclass.

In a programming language like Java this would be something like implementing an interface.

You might have already guessed that `Eq` provides the functions `==` and `/=`.
If you have more than one constraint the type signature looks like

```
fun :: (Ord a, Bounded a) => ...
```

to see what a typeclass provides you can look at the documentation on hackage or run `:info Ord` inside GHCi